# Imprimir em formato paisagem no crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Não consigo imprimir um relatório do Crystal em formato paisagem.
 
Já mudei em <kbd>Designer</kbd>><kbd>Printer Setup</kbd>><kbd>Orientation</kbd>><kbd>Landscape</kbd> mas não funcionou.
 
Fui no <kbd>Default Properties</kbd> também não funcionou.

Quanto visualizo o relatório via **VB.Net** sai em paisagem mas quando imprimo ele sai no formato retrato, cortando a parte à direita do relatório.

Alguém sabe o porquê disto?
Não posso ficar mudando no default da impressora pois cada relatório tem sua orientação (retrato ou paisagem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talvez assim?

```
rptTemp.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = PaperOrientation.Landscape
```

Sendo o objeto `rptTemp` o *report viewer*.

Comment: Voçe se importa de eu te mandar o codigo do rptPurchese.vb ?